# What causes the output of the flip-flop to be LOW in 555 timer monostable circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, flipflop, 555

[image: 555 timer monostable mode]

Before pressing the button, the external capacitor isn't charging because of the short circuit applied across it, but the short circuit is happening because discharge transistor is **ON** because the \$\overline{Q}\$ output is **HIGH**, so my question here "What causes the \$Q\$ output to be **LOW**"?

Comment: The pressing of the button?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I'm asking here before the button is pressed.

Comment: It's configured as a one-shot, so no button pressy, no pulse!

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: "Why the initial output of the flip-flop is LOW?"

Comment: Because nothing has happened to make it go high.

Comment: Can I ask: what's behind the question? Is it a homework/coursework question?

Comment: It either is low, or if it isn't, it will be.

Comment: His point: what if it so happened that the flip flop started High. It's possible since both Set and Reset are zero. In my answer I pointed that it comes to the same - it will soon turn low by itself as the circuit runs

Comment: @TonyM pure curiosity, why asking?

Comment: What's your answer, though?

Comment: @TonyM I thought that if the trigger voltage is above 1/3 Vcc, then the timer output must be LOW and therefore the not-Q output would be HIGH since it inverts the output, and that would switch on the transistor. but this answer is trivial for me and doesn't explain how the timer works with time forward.

Comment: ...but is it a homework/coursework question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think calling it a short circuit across the capacitor is a bit misleading:
The voltage below R1 is about 0.1 V because that's the transistor's saturation voltage. C1 charges to about 0.1 V and then acts as an open circuit - neither charges nor discharges. So I think it would be right to call C1 an open circuit. (A capacitor is a short circuit to fast switching current, but notice that in this case the circuit is stable at a DC state with an Active transistor, and so the capacitor achieves and maintains an open circuit voltage of 0.1 V - the voltage at the transistor's Collector).

To your question about why Q isn't high: let's say it were High, and the button not pressed. The transistor would have been cutoff. C1 in turn would have charged until the Reset Op Amp (the one on the top) turned to High output. With that the Flip flop's reset would have triggered. The reset of the flip flop would have turned Q low and !Q high. The transistor would have then Activated again, drawing current out of C1 until it's down to 0.1 V or so, at which point C1 is back to being an open circuit.
Along the way as the transistor is Active and C1 discharges, the Reset op amp would turn low again, resulting in the flip flop's input going back to zero & zero. But the flip flop remembers its state and Q (before the inverter) is stable at Low. (A button press could turn Q high, but it won't do so in of itself).

A good idea would be to try this on the Falstad circuit simulator (you can Google this free simulator). With a little patience a replica of the circuit above can be produced (in fact some 555 examples are available pre-made and can selected from the top menu of the simulator).

Comment: So the flip-flop can be at any of these two states initially, but change afterwards, is that right?

Comment: A correction, not the 2 states will change, only when Q=0.

Comment: Yes unless you Reset it manually, it can in principle start in either state. If it happens to start at Q=1 and not !Q=0 it will flip after a short while. If it starts at Q=0, !Q=1 like in the picture above - it won't flip spontaneously.

Comment: Notice there is also an inverter before the output, which inverts !Q. I'm referring to the value of !Q before inversion.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I like your question because it's a thoughtful question of trying to understand deeper. Nobody is going to ask this on a test, yet you want to see the full story. Sometimes I'm like that too. Sometimes I only understand something months later and in one case a year later. So the key is to persist.

Answer (score 0):

> *What causes the Q output to be LOW*

If \$\overline{Q}\$ is high then \$Q\$ has to be low in this scenario.

And, \$\overline{Q}\$ is high because \$S\$ isn't high.

\$S\$ is low because \$SW1\$ is open circuit.

Comment: but shouldn't you consider the 2 inputs together? I mean S and R are both 0 and this keeps the previous output unchanged, and from there came my question, there's no previous output so where did this state come from? [Edited]

Comment: Before it changed state, it was reset. Reset was due to the capacitor charging past the threshold and caused nQ to be high. That then discharged the capacitor rapidly but wouldn't cause a change of state in nQ or Q.

Answer (score 0):

When the 555 is initially powered, up a power-on-reset could be applied to the reset pin to prevent a power-up pulse being generated if it is important that the 555's output remains low at power-up. A power-on-reset would leave Q=0 and !Q=1.

Once the reset pin is taken high to remove the forced reset, an output pulse can be generated by the pressing of S1. A power-up pulse might also be generated if the reset pin is not held low for a short time at power-up.

After an output pulse, the RS latch will always be left with Q=0 and !Q=1. This is because the RS latch in a 555 timer consists of two cross-coupled NOR gates.

Initially Q=0 and !Q=1. Now S1 is pressed which takes the latch's 'S' input high resulting in Q=1 and !Q=0. S1 is released, 'S' goes low with no change at the latch's outputs.

The timing capacitor now starts to charge. When it reaches 2/3 of Vcc, the latch's 'R' input is taken high resulting in Q=0 and !Q=1. The timing capacitor rapidly discharges taking 'R' low with no effect on the latch's outputs. The timing cycle has completed leaving Q=0 and !Q=1.

To fully understand this you need to be conversant with the operation of a NOR gate RS latch. With this type of latch, taking an input momentarily high results in the opposite output being set high. The labeling convention is that taking 'S' high results in Q=1 and !Q=0 where as taking 'R' momentarily high results in Q=0 and !Q=1.

Comment: I understand the process after pressing the button, but I have a question here, if we connect the timer's reset pin with Vcc does that count as power-on-reset?

Comment: No, the reset pin must be held low for the timer to be  in reset. A power-on-reset would be implemented by holding the reset pin low during power-up and for a short period afterwards. The reset pin would then be taken high to Vcc to enable the timer to function. One way of implementing a power-on-reset would be with a resistor and capacitor - the voltage on the capacitor (and reset pin) lags behind the rising supply voltage at power-up thereby holding the timer in reset for a short period. A circuit configuration with the reset pin tied to the supply voltage doesn't implement a P-O-R.